# Changing variables inside conditional expectation

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, expected-value, conditional-expectation

Say we have a random variable $X$ on a probability space, taking values in the natural numbers. We want to compute $E(X)$. Letting $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and using the law of total expectation, $E(X) = E(E(X \mid X = n))$. It's obvious that we can't write $E(X \mid X = n) = E(n \mid X = n) = n \cdot E(1 \mid X = n) = n$, but what rules are we breaking if we do it? Intuitively, conditioned on that $X=n$ we should be left with the expectation of $n$, right?

Comment: $\mathbb E[X]=\mathbb E(\mathbb E(X\mid X=n))$ is wrong.

Comment: The constant $n\in\mathbb N$ has expectation $n\,.$ Q: "What rules are we breaking if we do it?" A: The rule of not messing around with notation and instead knowing what we are doing.